# FireMonkey - how to capture TScrollBar mouse events?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm trying to capture mouse events on a `TScrollBar`. In design time, I created a handler for each mouse event, on the `Events` tab of the `Object Inspector`. At runtime, the `TScrollBar` does not fire the mouse events, therefore the handlers are not executed. For instance, when the mouse pointer enters the `TScrollBar`, the `OnMouseEvent` never triggers the associated `ScrollBarMouseEnter`. I'm working with FireMonkey, Berlin 10.1 Update 2, Win32 platform. Any help would be appreciated.